# Se ejecuta el else cuando la primera condición se cumple

Tags: php, mysql, else

Hola me podrian ayudar por favor, tengo un error con una condición anidada en PHP la cual siempre se ejecuta el else cuando la primera condición se cumple, pero al momento de comentar toda la consulta para insertar los datos en el else me funciona correctamente las demás condiciones.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM horario";
    $result = $conexion->prepare($sql);
    $result->execute();
    $listTurns = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // VERIFICAR SI YA HAY UN REGISTRO CON ESTE ODONTOLOGO, DEPENDIENDO SI YA HUBO UN REGISTRO EN EL MISMO DIA
    foreach ($listTurns as $turns) {
        if ($turns['codPersonal'] == $personal && $turns['fecha'] == $fecha) {
            echo "
            <script>
                alert('¡Esté odontólogo COD: " . $personal . " ya tiene un turno para ese día!');
                window.location.href = '../programador/pag_inicio.php';
            </script>";
            // VERIFICAR SI HAY UN REGISTRO CON ESTE AUXILIAR ASIGNADO A UN ODONTOLOGO EL MISMO DIA Y RANGO DE HORA
        } elseif ($turns['asignar1'] == $asignar1 && $turns['fecha'] == $fecha) {
            if ($turns['horaInicio'] >= $hInicio . ":00" || $turns['horaFin'] <= $hFin . ":00") {
                echo "
                    <script>
                        alert('¡El turno entre esos horarios ya esta ocupado!');
                        window.location.href = '../programador/pag_inicio.php';
                    </script>  
                ";
            }
        } else { 
            $consulta = "INSERT INTO horario (fecha, horaInicio, horaFin, horasTrabajadas, codLabor, 
                          codPersonal, codSede, codUnidad, asignar1, asignar2, descripcionHorario)
                      VALUES ('$fecha', '$hInicio', '$hFin',  '$hTrabajadas', '$labor', '$personal', '$sede', '$unidad', 
                          '$asignar1', '$asignar2', '$descripcion')";
            $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
            $resultado->execute();
            header('Location:../programador/pag_inicio.php');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Estas seguro que siempre se ejecuta el else? o sera porque esto esta dentro de un foreach que se ejecuta para todos los campos, y en muchos de esos no se cumplen las condiciones? porque en lugar de hacer eso no le pedis a la db, con un query como corresponde, que se fije si se puede otorgar o no el turno?

Comment: Te agradezco por tú comentario, lo intentare pidiendoselo directamente a la db!

Comment: Tal cual. Estás recorriendo todos los registros de horario. Habrá unos en los que codPersonal == personal, otros en los que asignar1 == asignar1 y fecha = fecha... pero tienes que ver si hay otros en los que nada de lo anterior se cumple. Revisa el conjunto de datos que recibes al ejecutar el select, filtralo (la BD es muy eficiente haciéndolo) y así tus condiciones pueden ser más simples (y las controlarás mejor)

Comment: Aparte de que funcione o  no funcione, lo que hay aquí es un error de diseño. Las consultas a la base de datos son costosas, y si mandas datos desde un cliente se consumen también recursos de red. Hay formas de optimizar esto, para que no se consuman recursos sin necesidad, mejorando además la experiencia de usuario. Por ejemplo, puedes verificar de antemano los horarios y/o personas ocupados, para mostrarlos desactivados en el cliente, así, nunca se intentará escoger un horario / persona ocupados para luego verificar si lo está, no, ¡verifícalo de antemano!